# azure webjob break on error when running locally

Tags: visual-studio, azure-webjobs

This should be a easy one, but I have spent hours already on it.
I have a Azure webjob that is throwing an error.
I cannot get it to stop on the error, it just throws it up onto the screen and then keeps going.

[image: error]

I am using VS 2017
I have the type set to debug in the 'release/debug' drop down and I am starting it under the Debug menu.

This is making it extremely hard to debug my code!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: it would be better if you can provide the code.

Comment: The full error text would also be helpful.

Comment: I figured out how to do it, when I get back in tomorrow I will write up what I had to do.